# Не работает код регистрации PHP

Tags: php

Код выдаёт ошибку и данные пользователя не заносятся в БД, не могу понять в чём проблема.
Вот код: в самом верху подключение к базе, далее функции проверки и занесения в базу и вызов этих функций.

```
<?
define ('HOST', 'localhost');
define ('USER', 'root');
define ('PASS', '---');
define('DB', 'test');



function checkUserExists($mysqli, $login, $name)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=? or name=?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $login, $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
function regUser($mysqli, $login, $name, $pass)
{
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `name`, `pass`, `regdate`) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $login, $name, $pass);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$errors = [];
// другие проверки
// которые заполняют массив $errors
$user = checkUserExists($mysqli, $_POST['login']);
if ($user) {
    if ($user['login'] == $_POST['login']) {
        $errors[] = "логин занят";
    if ($user['name'] == $_POST['name']) {
        $errors[] = "Имя занят";
    }
}
}

if (!$errors) {
    regUser($mysqli, $_POST['login'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['pass']);
}
```

А вот сама ошибка: **Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function checkUserExists(), 2 passed in D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\AMAZON\setting.php on line 29 and exactly 3 expected in D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\AMAZON\setting.php:9 Stack trace: #0 D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\AMAZON\setting.php(29): checkUserExists(NULL, NULL) #1 D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\AMAZON\index.php(4): include_once('D:\OpenServer\O...') #2 {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\AMAZON\setting.php on line 9**

Comment: Чтобы понять, в чем проблема, надо засунуть текст ошибки в переводчик. Ты в курсе про то что в интернете существуют автоматические переводчики с английского на русский?

Comment: @Ипатьев, да я в курсе про переводчики и в ошибке написано что типа не все аргументы переданы функции checkUserExists в строчке **$user = checkUserExists($mysqli, $_POST['login']);** Но я уже менял по всякому и ошибка всё равно есть.

Comment: Ну так исправь это!

Comment: Не надо "менять по-всякому"! Надо делать нормально. И задавать **осмысленные вопросы.** Сейчас твой вопрос не имеет смысла, поскольку ты сам знаешь на него ответ.

Comment: @Ипатьев, изменения внёс и я так понимаю что может быть мой код вообще не совсем корректный, так как новая ошибка **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in** (я новичок товарищи, сильно не грузите).

Comment: Но ведь это **совсем другая ошибка**. Почему у тебя ошибка одна, а ты спрашиваешь про другую?

Comment: @Ипатьев, потому что сначала ошибка была одна а теперь эта вылезла после внесения изменений

Comment: В целом у тебя код неплохой, правильный. но тебе надо учиться работать с ошибками .Читать, переводить и гуглить. понятно что тебе они встречаются впервые, но нетрудно же сообразить, что ты не первый, кто с ними столкнулся. И в интернете примерно миллион ответов. Чтобы этой ошибки не было, надо соединяться с БД как показано здесь: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect#oop там много полезного но главное что вместо  Call to a member function будет выдаваться конкретная ошибка запроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, во-первых checkUserExists должна принимать 3 параметра, а вы передаёте 2 `$user = checkUserExists($mysqli, $_POST['login']);`. Также в самой функции в запросе у вас готовится 2 переменные, а вы передаёте тип только для 1: `$stmt->bind_param("s", $login, $name);`. Надо сделать `"ss"`. Также в функции `$conn` не объявлен, вместо него, вероятно, надо `$mysqli` написать, который вы передали.

Comment: изменения внёс и вышла новая ошибка **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in**, вообще добавил аргументы таким образом **$user = checkUserExists($mysqli, $_POST['login'], $_POST['name']);**

Comment: @ARTISUC, `$conn` на `$mysqli` поменяли?

Comment: да все изменил. Может быть вообще данный вариант кода вообще не подходит для регистрации пользователей?

Comment: Возможно ошибка в самом запросе. Проверьте его прямо в БД. Также я не вижу в приведённом коде где вы задаёте подключение к БД.

Comment: В самом начале кода ```<?
define ('HOST', 'localhost');
define ('USER', 'root');
define ('PASS', '---');
define('DB', 'test');```

Comment: @ARTISUC, это не подключения. Подключения это вот - `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");`. Через define вы ничего не делаете [prepare запрос](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: оу щет заработало!!!!!! Спасибо дорогой друг!!! РЕСПЕКТ ТЕБЕ ОГРОМНЫЙ!!!! Сейчас буду решать с авторизацией.

Comment: @ARTISUC, рад что помог. Вы можете принят ответ, если это действительно так.)

Comment: а можешь подсказать ещё [по данному вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144907/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-php). Там я дописал скрипт авторизации и он постоянно выводит НЕ ВЕРНЫЙ ЛОГИН ИЛИ ПАРОЛЬ.