# Почему не работает авторизация PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, авторизация, регистрация

Регистрация работает отлично, данные добавляются в базу, проверки все срабатывают как надо и вопросов нет, но вот авторизация мне пишет постоянно "НЕ ВЕРНЫЙ ЛОГИН ИЛИ ПАРОЛЬ".

Переадресация на главную не происходит, сессия не создаётся и вылазит только это сообщение.

```
<?php
//регистрация
function checkUser($mysqli, $login, $name) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=? or name=?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $login, $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
function regUser($mysqli, $login, $name, $pass) {
    $pass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `name`, `pass`, `regdate`) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $login, $name, $pass);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$errors = [];
$user = checkUser($mysqli, $_POST['login'], $_POST['name']);
if ($user && isset($_POST['enter'])) {
    if($_POST['login'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Введите логин";
    }
    if($_POST['name'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Введите отображаемое имя";
    }
    if($_POST['pass'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Введите пароль";
    }
    if($_POST['passconf'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Введите подтверждение пароля";
    }
    if ($user['login'] == $_POST['login']) {
        $errors[] = "Введённый логин уже занят";
    }
    if ($user['name'] == $_POST['name']) {
        $errors[] = "Введённое имя уже занято";
    }
}
if (!$errors) {
    regUser($mysqli, $_POST['login'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['pass']);
} else {
    $erro = '<div id="errors">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
}


//Скрипт авторизации
function loginUser($mysqli, $login, $name, $pass, $regdate) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=? or name=? or pass=? or regdate=?");
    $pass = password_verify($_POST['pass'], $user['pass']); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $login, $name, $pass, $regdate);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
$userlog = loginUser($mysqli, $user['login'], $user['name'], $user['pass'], $user['regdate']);
if (isset($_POST['go'])) {
    if($_POST['login'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Вы не ввели логин";
    }
    if($_POST['pass'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Вы не ввели пароль";
    }
    if ($user['login'] != $_POST['login']) {
        $errors[] = "Неверный логин или пароль";
    }
    if ($user['pass'] != $_POST['pass']) {
        $errors[] = "Неверный логин или пароль";
    }
}
if (!$errors && $userlog) {
        $_SESSION['USER_NAME'] = $user['name'];
        $_SESSION['USER_REGDATE'] = $user['regdate'];
        $_SESSION['USER_LOGIN_IN'] = 1;
        exit(header('Location: /'));
} else {
    $error = '<div id="errors">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$userlog` будет пустым потому, что функция `loginUser` ничего не возвращает из-за пропущенного `return`, а мы получим код из else в условии `if (!$errors && $userlog) {...}`. Если это 1 файл, а не 2, то после скрипта регистрации идёт сразу скрипт авторизации. При удачной регистрации `$user` будет пустым, потому что проверка функцией `checkUser` вернула пустой результат, как и задумано. Следовательно условия `$user['login'] != $_POST['login']` или `$user['pass'] != $_POST['pass']` сработают в любом случае.

Почему при авторизации вы проверяете ещё и имя вместе с датой регистрации? Можно же проверять по введённому логину и паролю, как это почти везде происходит. Учитывая все ошибки, функцию `loginUser` лучше переписать, как и дальнейший код. К примеру так.

```
function loginUser($mysqli, $login, $pass) {
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=? AND pass=?");
  $pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $login, $pass);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
  return $user;
}
$userlog = loginUser($mysqli, $_POST['login'], $_POST['pass']);
if (isset($_POST['go'])) {
  if($_POST['login'] == ''){
    $errors[] = "Вы не ввели логин";
  }
  if($_POST['pass'] == ''){
    $errors[] = "Вы не ввели пароль";
  }
  if(empty($userlog)){
    $errors[] = "Неверный логин или пароль";
  }
}
if (!$errors && $userlog) {
  $_SESSION['USER_NAME'] = $userlog['name'];
  $_SESSION['USER_REGDATE'] = $userlog['regdate'];
  $_SESSION['USER_LOGIN_IN'] = 1;
  exit(header('Location: /'));
} else {
  $error = '<div id="errors">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
}
```

**P.S**

Действительно. Код в функции будет работать не корректно тк `password_hash` постоянно новые значения задаёт. Можно попробовать сделать следующие изменения. Должно сработать.

```
function loginUser($mysqli, $login, $pass) {
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=?");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $login);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
  if(password_verify($pass, $user['pass'])){
    return $user;
  }
}
```

Comment: ваш пример выводит сейчас сообщение НЕ ВЕРНЫЙ ЛОГИН ИЛИ ПАРОЛЬ и я думаю (но это не точно), что это из-за несовпадения паролей, так как в БД пароль захэшированный и соответственно его нужно вытащить и расхэшировать заменив строчку **$pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);** на эту строчку **$pass = password_verify($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);** ...........может быть в этом ошибка или нет?

Comment: И да, код регистрации и авторизации находятся в одном файле. А как лучше сделать, разместить их в разные файлы?

Comment: @ARTISUC, не совсем. Мы получаем через post не хэшированную версию пароля. Если просто подставить принятые данные, то мы в запросе к БД будем сравнивать хэшированный пароль и нет. Поэтому нужно их к одному виду привести, что сделано через `password_hash`

Comment: Тогда, если всё верно, почему же код выдаёт сообщение НЕВЕРНЫЙ ЛОГИН ИЛИ ПАРОЛЬ?

Comment: А если выдаёт `Неверный логин или пароль`, то что-то не так либо с условием `empty($userlog)`, либо с условием `!$errors && $userlog`. Попробуйте через echo проверить что не так

Comment: Не работает! сделал **echo "ok"** после проверки **empty($userlog)** и всё выводит OK, а если что-то не так с условием !$errors && $userlog, то я так понимаю значит что то не так со всей функцией **function loginUser($mysqli, $login, $pass)**

Comment: @ARTISUC, Дополнил ответ

Comment: ничего не работает с вашим дополнением, но с другой стороны скрипт вроде рабочий. Вообщем по ходу нашёл я ошибку, но теперь не могу понять как её устранить....................Проблема как мне кажется в функциях **password_hash** и **password_verify**.......................а понял я это, когда закомментировал строку **$pass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);** в скрипте регистрации и соответственно после этого пароли при регистрации не хэшируются и авторизация проходит на ура! Вот теперь пытаюсь понять, как это устранить. Может быть есть какие-нибудь варианты решения?